# What is the best way of storing a discontinuous range of numbers in python?

Tags: python, set

I would like to handle a discontinuous range of numbers in python and check if one range is a subset of another range or find intersections between two ranges.

If I represent it using sets:

```py
range_1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 21, 22, 23, 24}
range_2 = {2, 3, 4, 11}
range_3 = {11, 12, 13}

print(range_2.issubset(range_1)) # True
print(range_1 & range_3) # {11}
```

The above works great for small set of numbers, but I want to handle integers of the order of millions. Sets takes up a lot of memory if I expand the ranges and store them and takes a lot of time if I expand them on the fly.

Is there a better way than sets?

Comment: Is there an algorithm defining your groups? Is there a significant difference between the numbers included and the numbers excluded?

Comment: The related question mentions the package [pyinterval](https://pyinterval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html), which might be interesting for you

Comment: Asking for *the best way* without more context is likely to attract opinion only answers. There are different containers for a reason: each of them has it pros and cons. List is simple to use and reasonably memory efficient but has linear search, set is more memory consuming but has hashed search, arrays are very memory efficient but cannot be expanded and have also linear search. Without more context, I am afraid that this question is off topic here.

Comment: I think "better way" is pretty arbitrary for your question. Sets are the fastest, lists are flexible, and arrays are memory efficient. Decide which one best suits your needs and that will be the "better way" to approach this problem.

Comment: I wanted it to be both fast and memory effiient. But I guess there is no 'best way'.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere There are no algorithm defining the groups. The numbers could be any random positive number, ranging anywhere between 1 and tens of millions. There is no hard upper limit. Also, there is no particular bias towards numbers included or numbers excluded.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am trying to create a class to represent Finite element Analysis components. These components are collections of 'nodes' or 'elements' which an analysis engineer decides to create (for various reasons like applying loads and boundary conditions or post processing etc). The nodes or elements that the person decides to include in the component may be random (most of the times by visual selection in an analysis software). Quite often, we need to export these sets in to various other programs for further post processing. I thought a python module will help the cause.